# Stylus, использование calc() в миксинах не работает с переменными. Есть ли костыль?

Tags: css, css3, препроцессор, stylus

[image: Можно посмотреть на скриншоте наглядно]

В итоге должна работать так:

```
adaptiv-text(minFontSize, minWidthDisplay, plusFontSize, maxWidth)
  // (минимальный размер текста)
  font-size: (minFontSize)rem
  // (минимальная ширина)
  @media screen and (min-width: (minWidthDisplay)em)
    // (минимальный размер текста + максимальное прибавление (не трогаем - не трогаем) / (максимальная ширина - не трогаем))
    font-size: calc( (minFontSize)rem + plusFontSize * (100vw - (minWidthDisplay)rem) / (maxWidth - minWidthDisplay) )
    // (максимальная ширина)
  @media (min-width: (maxWidth)em)
    // (минимальный font-size + максимальное прибавление)
    font-size: calc( (minFontSize)rem + (plusFontSize)rem )
```

h1
  adaptiv-text(2, 20, 2, 100)

Comment: это может помочь? http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=%24inner-padding%20%3D%2020px%0A%0A.thing%0A%20%20transform%20scale(0.8)%20translateX(%22calc(20%25%20-%20%25s)%22%20%25%20%24inner-padding)

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
    adaptiv-text(minFontSize, minWidthDisplay, plusFontSize, maxWidth)
      minFontSize = (minFontSize)rem
      minWidthDisplay = (minWidthDisplay)rem
      plusFontSize = (plusFontSize)rem
      maxWidth = (maxWidth)em
      // (минимальный размер текста)
      font-size: (minFontSize)rem
      // (минимальная ширина)
      @media screen and (min-width: (minWidthDisplay)em)
        // (минимальный размер текста + максимальное прибавление (не трогаем - не трогаем) / (максимальная ширина - не трогаем))
        font-size: "calc( %s + %d * (100vw - %s) / (%d - %d))" % (minFontSize plusFontSize minWidthDisplay maxWidth minWidthDisplay)
        // (максимальная ширина)
      @media (min-width: maxWidth)
        // (минимальный font-size + максимальное прибавление)
        font-size: "calc( %s + %s )" % (minFontSize (plusFontSize))

    h1
      adaptiv-text(2, 20, 2, 100)
```